# How to render lists using React Native and Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm doing Expo React Native Application using Firestore Database. I'm following the below Tutorial.
[Tutorial](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage-with-flatlists)

```js
    function ViewServices  () {
   
 
    const navigation =useNavigation();
    const [FullData, setFullData] = useState([]);
    const [driverData, setDriverData] = useState([]);

    // Retrieving Data 
    useEffect(() => { 
     
    firebase.firestore().collection('driver')
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('Empty');
          return;
          }
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            driverData.push(
              {                           
              id: doc.id,        
            });          
         });
         {      
              driverData? driverData.map((point) => (
              firebase.firestore().collection('driver')
              .doc(point.id)
              .collection('personal')
              .get()
              .then(snapshot => {
                  if (snapshot.empty) {
                  alert('Nothing To Show');
                  return;
                  }
                  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    FullData.push(
                      {  
                       id : doc.id,                       
                       name: (doc.data().firstname),
                       school: (doc.data().lastname),                                     
                      });          
                  }); 
                  setFullData(FullData);
                       
                })   
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
              })        
              ))
          : null}               
        })   
      .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
     }, []);
     
      return(          
     <FlatList
      data={FullData}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{ height: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', 
          justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>User ID: {item.id}</Text>
          <Text>User Name: {item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
    )}
```

However the data are retrieved fine. But the lists are only shown when I manually press Refresh (Ctrl+S)

How can I retrieve the lists when the screen loads? Please let me know.

Comment: You need to past some code you're working on, so people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

The problem happened because the components are firstly rendered before the data fetching. That's why it required manual refresh.

I have added Activity Indicator component and it will be loaded until the data fetched. After the data successfully fetched, activity indicator will be replaced with flat list component.

```
function ViewServices  () {

**const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)**
const navigation =useNavigation();
const [FullData, setFullData] = useState([]);
const [driverData, setDriverData] = useState([]);

// Retrieving Data 
useEffect(() => { 
 
firebase.firestore().collection('driver')
.get()
.then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('Empty');
      return;
      }
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        driverData.push(
          {                           
          id: doc.id,        
        });          
     });
     {      
          driverData? driverData.map((point) => (
          firebase.firestore().collection('driver')
          .doc(point.id)
          .collection('personal')
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
              if (snapshot.empty) {
              alert('Nothing To Show');
              return;
              }
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                FullData.push(
                  {  
                   id : doc.id,                       
                   name: (doc.data().firstname),
                   school: (doc.data().lastname),                                     
                  });          
              }); 
              setFullData(FullData);
              **setLoading(false);** 
                   
            })   
          .catch(err => {
              console.log('Error getting documents', err);
          })        
          ))
      : null}               
    })   
  .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
 }, []);

**if (loading) { 
return (
<ActivityIndicator  size="large" color="#00ff00" justifyContent= "center"/>
)
}**

else{

  return(          
 <FlatList
  data={FullData}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ height: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', 
      justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>User ID: {item.id}</Text>
      <Text>User Name: {item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
)
}   
}
```